# Modal open and close not working properly

Tags: react-native

I have added the below reusable code to show Modal and close the Modal when clicked outside of that Modal, when I click on a button the Modal is shown and when I click outside of that Modal it gets closed till here it is working properly but again when I click on a button to open Modal, the Modal is not shown, and I can't use props on  can anyone tell me any other solution and what mistake I have made in the below code.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, FlatList,TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
  visible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}
const BottomSheet: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const [showBottomSheet,setBottomSheet]=useState(true);

  if(showBottomSheet){
    return (
      <Modal animationType={ANIMATIONS.SlideType} transparent={true} visible={props.visible}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> setBottomSheet(false)}>
          <View style={Styles.opacityContainer}></View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={Styles.container}>
          <View style={Styles.headerContainer}>
            <View style={[Styles.header, Styles.directionRow]}>
              <View>
                <Text style={Styles.headerText}>Add</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={Styles.iconContainer}>
                <Icon
                  name={cancel}
                  size={18}
                  IconClick={props.onClose}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.viewContainer}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <FlatList
                horizontal={false}
                data={props.navData}
                renderItem={renderActions}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              />
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

This is the other file where I am using the above reusable component

customer.tsx

```
const [showBottomSheet, setShowBottomSheet] = useState(false);
  const hideBottomSheet = () => {
    setShowBottomSheet(false);
  };


 <View style={Styles.profileContainer}>
    <AddButton
      onButtonPress={() => {
        setShowBottomSheet(true);
      }}
      iconObject={{
        iconName: plus,
        iconSize: Sizes.plusLargeSize,
      }}
    />
    <BottomSheet
      visible={showBottomSheet}
      onClose={hideBottomSheet}
    />
  </View>
```